# How to completely omit an element when doing a dataDowncast in CKEditor5

Tags: ckeditor5, ckeditor5-plugin

I have a custom plugin and have a transient element that exists in the model, and also in the editor view.  However, when I do a dataDowncast conversion, I want to completely omit the element from the data view.

If I omit the dataDowncast conversion completely, I get a `conversion-model-consumable-not-consumed` error.

If you are wondering *why* I need this.  I am doing a custom upload support, and I am showing the upload progress in the editor.  However, I don't want to save that upload progress element, as it is transient and only for improved user experience, and it gets replace with a 'real' element when the upload completes.

Any thoughts?